# Session_store undefined method during upgrade of Rails 1.2.3 to Rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

Here I migrate Rails 1.2.3 application into Rails 3.1.1. But I am facing a strange issue of session_store.

> ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:37:in
>   `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>': undefined method`
>   session_store=' for ActionController::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this post helped me to fix it,

[ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `debug_rjs=' for ActionView::Base:Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718541/error-nomethoderror-undefined-method-debug-rjs-for-actionviewbaseclass)

...to fix the error just search in your environment files, development.rb, production.rb or stagging.rb for something like

```
config.session_store=
```

and comment out  that line

```
# config.session_store=
```

hope this help!

Comment: Thanks @Julian, You answered the one and half year ago asked question. +1 Vote For Your Effort. :) I have done the same steps at that time but forget to answer at Stack Overflow. Thanks.